# Web app navbar working on android, not iOS.. CSS issue

Tags: html, css, ios, reactjs, next.js

I have a Nextjs web app featuring a navbar with a hamburger menu, logo and an avatar. In desktop (chrome, mozilla, brave - developer tools mobile mode) the navbar works perfectly fine. In chrome on an android phone the navbar works perfectly fine.

In any browser on iPhone X, 11 & 12, **the navbar is completely unresponsive, unclickable on pages that are scrollable**.

On these pages I have the navbar rendered and then a container with this pages contents. This container has the following css:
`// style={{ overflow: "hidden", overflowY: "scroll", height: "100%" }}`

If I remove this piece of css, the navbar is working again but obviously the component is unscrollable, another undesirable result.

I have tried this both inline and in css modules with the same result. This is very annoying since it works perfectly on desktop & android. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Hel.lo!Try to remove the overflow: "hidden" entirely, set overflowX to hidden, and overflowY to auto.
That way the X is always hidden, and the Y is scrollable if it needs to.
Hope that works!